# How to send logs to ServiceEventSource from outside of Service Fabric?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-service-fabric

I'm not even sure if this is possible but I have my Service Fabric microservices sending log information to ServiceEventSource by using:

```
ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, "this is my log message");
```

My external (non-Service Fabric) application consumes the Stateless WebAPI (Service Fabric) but it currently logs to a text file. Is there a way to have my external applications somehow also log to ServiceEventSource so I don't have to look in both places?

Comment: A bit off-topic, but in cases like this where you have different sources for logs, I would recommend using single place for collection, like DB/table storage or one of the more robust logging solutions like logstash or splunk which have forwarders/appenders for different services/applications.

Comment: Where are you outputting the events of `ServiceEventSource` to? You could create a separate `EventSource` for the external service and have a library like Diagnostics Evenflow (https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow) forward those events of both sources to a single destination.

Answer (score 0):

Simply share the `ServiceEventSource` class with your external application. You could do this by simply sharing the code or by packaging it in a NuGet package or by referencing the built .dll in your external application.

A word of caution: EventSource and ETW logging in general is *very* picky. Your definition of the EventSource really should be identical in both places, our it will very likely not work at all, or fail in strange and hard to understand ways.

Comment: thanks, @yoape! I'll give this a shot and report back with results.